# Recovering lost chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome

recently had a driver issue that after exhausting all options, forced me to reinstall Windows. In an attempt to move my chrome setup, tabs etc over I copied the chrome folder located at appdata\local. With my new windows install I've moved that folder to the same directory and it doesn't seem to be change anything. Had some really important tabs open that I need to recover, am I out of luck?

I see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/341068/how-can-i-load-my-last-tabs-into-chrome-using-last-tabs-last-session-files) answer here, however my saved copy of AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default appears to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate it mentioned in the menu when searching for a tab if you wish to open a tab that you recently closed. In fact, you may view recently closed tabs on every computer and mobile device connected to your account if you sync your Chrome browser across devices.

Comment: thanks, however this isn't relevant as I have already reinstalled windows and if I had synced my chrome to google account I wouldn't be asking this.